# No binary for PhantomJS browser on your platform. Please, set "PHANTOMJS_BIN" env variable

Tags: phantomjs, karma-runner, mocha-phantomjs, karma-mocha, karma-coverage

My package.json looks like this..

```
"karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.1.4",
"karma-safari-launcher": "^0.1.1",
"karma-sinon-chai": "~0.2.0",
"karma-spec-reporter": "~0.0.16",
"mocha": "~1.20.1"
```

my npm version is 2.2.0

whay am I getting this when I run karma test - karma start my.conf.js

Comment: The message is pretty clear: there's no PhantomJS installed on your machine. `karma-phantomjs-launcher` should download a binary of PhantomJS and install on your machine if available: because it's not you have to manually install yourself and then add its path to the environment variables using the `PHANTOMJS_BIN`.

Comment: @MarcoCI I do have the same problem and there actually is a binary of phantomjs being installed together with the `karma-phantomjs-launcher`.

Comment: @Flek: then export the path of that file as shown in the answer below.

Comment: I fixed it by removing karma-phantomjs-launcher and phantomjs and running npm install

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I was having this issue with an older version of node, too.  If you don't want to have to hard-code this environment variable, updating your version of node will solve the problem.  Just do the following (OSX instructions):

```
npm uninstall -g phantomjs
npm cache clean -f
brew upgrade nodejs
rm -rf node_modules
npm install -g YOUR_GLOBAL_DEPENDENCIES
npm install
```

Edit: updated instructions to make sure there is no global phantomjs dependency

Comment: These commands initially seemed to cause more problems then solutions but I eventually worked through them. `brew upgrade nodejs` didn't work out for me, I got `Error: node not installed`. But it seems that just unistalling phantomjs, cleaning npm cache, and reinstalling packages with npm cleared my `No binary for PhantomJS browser on your platform. Please, set “PHANTOMJS_BIN” env variable` error. Thank you!

Comment: exactly why i didnt want to embark on them.  i physically downgraded node to cure another problem.  no time for that tonite

Comment: I am able to do this for the first time, but every time I close my system and restart the app, I have to do this again. Is there a way to permanently get rid of this error?

Comment: I also ran into issues with npm after doing the upgrade... `npm install` would simply quit after a deprecation warning. Physically downloading the latest from [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/en/) fixed it for me

Answer (score 19):

This seems to be an issue with phantom js runner and phantom js versions.

https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-phantomjs-launcher/issues/31

How I fixed my issue..

```
   # install 
   npm install -g karma-phantomjs-launcher

   # temporary path.. set the path
   export PHANTOMJS_BIN=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs

   karma start my.conf.js
```

Answer (score 12):

I ran into this same problem. The fix is to manually set the `PHANTOMJS_BIN` variable to point to the correct phantomjs path. Somehow karma launcher tries to look at the wrong path set by `PHANTOMJS_BIN`.

Here is what worked for me:

```
$ echo $PHANTOMJS_BIN
```

> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs

```
$ export PHANTOMJS_BIN=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs

$ grunt test
```

everything is ok after that.

Answer (score 4):

I hit this problem with karma-phantomjs-launcher@1.0.0, where I had also installed phantomjs@2.1.3.

Turns out that phantomjs is deprecated, replaced with phantomjs-prebuilt.

Uninstalling both packages and reinstalling phantomjs-prebuilt fixed the problem with karma-phantomjs-launcher:

```
npm -g remove phantomjs phantomjs-prebuilt
npm -g install phantomjs-prebuilt
```

Answer (score 4):

I remove all my node_modules folder under my Project and run "npm install". This did fix my problem.

Answer (score 2):

My `karma.conf.js` had this line: `process.env.PHANTOMJS_BIN = 'node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/.bin/phantomjs';` at the top. I just realized that! I commented it, and it works

Answer (score 2):

I met the same issue sometimes. I have a `gruntfile.js` and I had `package.json` where I explicitly add `phantomjs-prebuilt` as dependency. But my CI Server sometimes can run `grunt karma` smoothly while sometimes fails claiming `No binary for PhantomJS browser on your platform. Please, set “PHANTOMJS_BIN” env variable`.

So I add a `grunt task` to ensure the `PHANTOMJS_BIN` variable was set before the test runs, and then solved the annoying issue.

```
grunt.registerTask('ensurePhantomJsPath', function () {
    process.env.PHANTOMJS_BIN = './node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/bin/phantomjs';
    console.log(process.env.PHANTOMJS_BIN);
});
```

So finally the `Gruntfile.js` looks like this:

```
grunt.registerTask('ensurePhantomJsPath', function () {
    process.env.PHANTOMJS_BIN = './node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/bin/phantomjs';
    console.log(process.env.PHANTOMJS_BIN);
});

grunt.registerTask('test', ['ensurePhantomJsPath', 'karma']);
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem on OSX:  Remove and create file `karma.config.js` using sudo.

Answer (score 1):

had same problem, did all above, no result
just deleted 'karma-phantomjs-launcher' folder from global node_modules and project local, 
called 'npm install' and all is fine!

Answer (score 1):

Ran into a problem like this one. What I did was install the phantomjs globally `npm install -g phantomjs`. Then went to the `karma-phantomjs-launcher` module folder and opened `index.js` file. Then I went to the `phantomJSExePath` function and commented out the prior contents(not sure if it is safe to do what I did). Then I placed

```
return 'C://Users/user/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/phantomjs.exe';
```

Saved me from retyping the temporary export.

Answer (score 1):

Run the below commands:

```
npm remove phantomjs -g
npm remove phantomjs
npm install phantomjs
```

Once you do this installation:

you will get a message like the below one:

```
Linking to global install at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs
```

Copy this path and run:

```
export PHANTOMJS_BIN=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs
```

Basically what is happening is: karma is trying to launch the browser but unable to find its bin. 
Once you export the path to the correct path, it runs.